# Transpose multiple rows into columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose, vba

I've came across this task and I'm stuck big time. I've tried a PivotTable but it didn't give me the desired result. The only thing that works is a manual transpose but the number of records is 5k odd.

What I'm trying to achieve here is to transpose the data from rows for the company into columns so at a later stage to be able to count the number of votes and average per company.

[image: SO33969916 question example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PivotTable can do the job. All you need is a helper column using `COUNTIFS`. Notice the formula in cell D2.

[image]

And the PivotTable would look like this (set to Tabular Layout)

[image]

[image]

A note to take here is `COUNTIFS` can get really slow when the number of records grow to around 10k or more (or just my slow pc :/). When this happens, the workaround is: first sort your data, then use `COUNTIFS` over a limited number of cells only. For example, at cell D2, the formula will be `=COUNTIFS(A2:A102,A2,B2:B102,B2)`, hence counting only 100 records rather than the whole bunch as you fill down the formula.

Comment: Someone gave me other solution but I will explore yours as well. Just to keep the answers in the loop here's what's been suggested (and worked):

You could create the structure with the following formulae:
• In D2 =IF(B2<>OFFSET(B2,-1,0),C2,"")
• In E2 =IF(D2<>"",IF(OFFSET($D2,COLUMN()-4,)="",IF(OFFSET($C2,COLUMN()-4,)="","",OFFSET($C2,COLUMN()-4,)),""),"")
Copy the E2 formula across to, say, Z2 (i.e. enough to accommodate the maximum # entries for any one company), then copy D2:Z2 down as far as needed.

Comment: Looks good too. So you can use the formulae version that update itself dynamically, or the PivotTable version which i think is easier to use (without needing very long formulae) but will need to refresh the table to update the values. Its up to you, have fun! :)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the number of votes and average per company, that can be done in a variety of ways.

Using a Pivot Table, drag companies to the rows area; drag rating to the values area twice.  Then change the Value Field setting on one of the Ratings to Count; and on the other to Average.

Add some formatting and various options gives you:

[image]

Or if you have a list of the Organizations (Company Names) in, let us say, G3:Gn, and your data table in columns A:C, you can use formulas:

```
Count:    H3: =COUNTIF($B$1:$B$1000,G3)
Average:  I3: =AVERAGEIF($B$1:$B$1000,G3,C1:$C$1000)
```

And fill down as far as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned a PT did not suit , assuming `RATING` is in F2, please try in G3 copied down to suit:

```
=IF(AND(COLUMN()-7<COUNTIF($E:$E,$E3),$E2<>$E3),OFFSET($F3,COLUMN()-7,0),"")
```

then drag all the formulae to the right until an entire column appears blank. Note this requires the `TARGET ATTENDEE ORGANIZATION` column be sorted.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your ideas!